# Unity - moving an object around a radius

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, mathematics, rotation

I'm trying to move a 2D object around the mouse position, However, i want to constrain the object from rotating unnaturally around itself, i want it to basically rotate around a radius, similar to how a boat moves. I've provided the boat example below of what i am trying to achieve, the game is called battleboats.io and their rotation around the mouse will not skid, it looks natural like propellers pushing from behind.

[image: This is what i'm looking for]

Here's my code for achieving this in unity:

```
public Camera camera;
public Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

private float rotationSpeed = 200f;
private float acceleration = 4.4f;

Vector3 GetMousePosition(Camera c)
{
    return c.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 direction = GetMousePosition(camera) - transform.position;
    direction.Normalize();
    float rotationAngle = Vector3.Cross(direction, transform.up).z;

    //rotation
    rigidbody.angularVelocity = -rotationAngle * rotationSpeed;

    //forward momentum
    rigidbody.velocity = transform.up * acceleration;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

What i currently have and the result of my code is illustrated in the below gif. 
[image: This is what i have]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put a cap on how big `rotationAngle` is allowed to be.  Right now, as the difference between the mouse and the "player" grows larger, your "player" rotates more quickly to catch up. But in order to put a "minimum turn radius" on your object, you need to restrict how quickly it can change direction.

Try this:

```
float rotationAngle = Vector3.Cross(direction, transform.up).z;

//apply a maximum turn angle of 25 degrees
rotationAngle = Mathf.Max(Mathf.Min(rotationAngle,25), -25);

//rotation
rigidbody.angularVelocity = -rotationAngle * rotationSpeed;
```

Adjust the "25/-25" as needed to achieve the desired turn rate.

Comment: That did the trick! I forgot to normalize the direction as well. Thank you :)